# Django admin change view not change in linux

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a change for the model in the templates folder, I added a button to object tools. In Windows, the change works without a problem; on Linux, the change cannot be seen.

I restarted nginx, gunicorn. I tried collections static and it didn't help. I put the same version of django on linux also didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the name of the folder to lower case